# Обработка нажатия на пункт меню pywin32 в PyQT5

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, gui, pywin32

У меня есть небольшой графический интерфейс, написанный на **Python PyQT5**. При нажатии на иконку окна в **Windows** всплывает встроенное меню. Стоит задача немного переопределить это меню, а именно - добавить пункт "о программе", при нажатии на который будет открываться небольшое окно с информацией. Я не нашел простого способа переопределить это встроенное меню с помощью **PyQT5**, но мне подсказали, как сделать это используя **pywin32**.
Я делаю это, добавляя следующий код:

```
        self.custom_menu_id = 6
        hwnd = self.winId()
        hmenu = win32gui.GetSystemMenu(hwnd, False)
        win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_SEPARATOR, 5, '')
        win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_STRING, self.custom_menu_id, 'О программе')
```

Остается вопрос, как мне связать нажатие на этот пункт меню с открытием диалогового окна с некоторой информацией в PyQT5?
Ниже будет полный код программы (для того, чтобы его запустить нужны библиотеки PyQt5==5.15.8 и pywin32==305) и скриншоты окна с выпадающим меню.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import win32gui
import win32.lib.win32con as win32con


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # конфигурация главного окна
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_main_window)

        # тут добавляю новый пункт меню:
        self.custom_menu_id = 6
        hwnd = self.winId()
        hmenu = win32gui.GetSystemMenu(hwnd, False)
        win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_SEPARATOR, 5, '')
        win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_STRING, self.custom_menu_id, 'О программе')
        
        # конфигурация верхней панели инструментов
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addStretch(1)
        self.btn_start_reading = QPushButton("Считать")
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_start_reading)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_toolbar_buttons)

        # конфигурация таблицы
        self.layout_table = QHBoxLayout()
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(9)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['№', 'Дата и время', 'БКУ', 'КЛ', 'АУ', 'Канал', 'Код события', 'Доп. параметр', 'Описание'])
        self.layout_table.addWidget(self.table)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

всплывающее меню с пунктом "О программе":

[image: всплывающее меню:]

Comment: проще уже скрыть оригинальный заголовок и нарисовать свой. Qt платформонезависим и врядли даст виндовые костыли городить, а добавленный вами пункт меню надо ловить в процедуре обработки сообщений, а установить виндовый хук из питона попахивает извращением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересный кейс, хотя его полезность и близится к нулю)

Все же Вам придется вмешиваться в эвентлуп приложения, но на счастье в `QWidget` для этих целей есть виртуальный метод [nativeEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) (в старых Qt назывался `winEvent`). На всякий случай обращаю внимание что для macos и linux `nativeEvent` также есть, но работать будет иначе.

Согласно WinAPI, когда пользователь выбирает команду из системного меню, окно приложения получает сообщение [WM_SYSCOMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand). в `wParam` при этом может принимать одно из предопределенных значений (см. документацию) или идентификатор пункта меню, который Вы добавляли.

В общем и целом, реализация будет примерно такая:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import win32gui
import win32.lib.win32con as win32con
import ctypes.wintypes


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    # Нам надо определить свой обработчик событий эвентлупа
    def nativeEvent(self, eventType, message):
        retval, result = super(MainWindow,self).nativeEvent(eventType, message)
        # из параметра message нам надо получить стандартную структуру типа MSG
        msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG.from_address(message.__int__())
        # Что-то тыкнули в системном меню
        if msg.message == win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            # И судя по идентификатору - то что нам надо
            if msg.wParam == self.custom_menu_id:
                QMessageBox.information(self, "бляблябля", "Ебаут програм")
        return retval, result

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # конфигурация главного окна
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_main_window)

        # тут добавляю новый пункт меню:
        self.custom_menu_id = 0xFF
        hwnd = self.winId()
        hmenu = win32gui.GetSystemMenu(hwnd, False)
        win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_SEPARATOR, 5, '')
        m = win32gui.AppendMenu(hmenu, win32con.MF_STRING, self.custom_menu_id, 'О программе')



        # конфигурация верхней панели инструментов
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addStretch(1)
        self.btn_start_reading = QPushButton("Считать")
        self.layout_toolbar_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_start_reading)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_toolbar_buttons)

        # конфигурация таблицы
        self.layout_table = QHBoxLayout()
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(9)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['№', 'Дата и время', 'БКУ', 'КЛ', 'АУ', 'Канал', 'Код события', 'Доп. параметр', 'Описание'])
        self.layout_table.addWidget(self.table)
        self.layout_main_window.addLayout(self.layout_table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: хорошо сказано :) +

Comment: @Sergey Tatarintsev. Прекрасно, спасибо! Это то, что я искал.

Answer (score 0):

Можно привязаться на `QMessageBox.about()`

```
def menu_action_triggered(self, action):
    if action == self.custom_menu_id:
        QMessageBox.about(self, 'О программе', 'Инфа')
```

Ну и соответственно привязка:

```
menu = self.menuBar()
menu.triggered.connect(self.menu_action_triggered)
```

Comment: это не то, чего бы я хотел. Меню, открывающееся по нажатию на иконку окна - это не объект menuBar главного окна. Это меню я не определял, оно создается автоматически. Мне нужно получить доступ именно к нему.